# Which filters or effects etc. are being used in these photos?

Tags: post-processing, reverse-engineering

The photos in question are the ones of the "culturemakers" on the the [kony2012](http://kony2012.com) campaign  homepage - e.g. Mark Zuckerburg, Oprah etc.

I'm especially interested in how they:

1. Make darker colors more prominent
2. Wash out the lighter colors
3. Add the checked noise to the image (it doesn't really look like another image beneath an opaque layer)

Also, I use GIMP as opposed to photoshop but hopefully I'll be able to work out any references to photoshop (or other app) anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Saturation down
2. Contrast way up
3. Halftone filter

Comment: I bow before your wisdom, this has put me on the right track. Thanks for helping out a noob.